# Law in USA the limits Medicare Part B premiums?

Tags: united-states, us-federal-government

What is the law in the USA that prevents the government from raising Medicare Part B premiums more than a small amount each year?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant law is [42 USC 1395r](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/1395r), which regulates the setting of premiums, though it doesn't say anything about "a small amount". The premiums are based in part on projected costs, so if actual costs quadruple in a year, premiums will increase (also, premiums for an individual can increase substantially if their income does).